# Как отобразить только 10 элементов массива?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Как отобразить 10 элементов массива, в зависимости от страницы?

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { fetchUsers, removeUser } from '../redux/actions/usersAction'
import { getUsers } from '../redux/selectors/usersSelector'
import { List, Image, Button,Pagination } from 'semantic-ui-react'
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

export default function Users() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();  
  const users = useSelector(getUsers);
  const [ currentPage, setCurrentPage ] = useState(1)

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchUsers());
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <Pagination defaultActivePage={currentPage} firstItem={null} lastItem={null} pointing secondary totalPages={3} onClick={(e) => setCurrentPage(e.target.getAttribute('value'))}/>

      <List divided verticalAlign='middle'>
        {users.slice((currentPage * 10), currentPage * 10 + 10).map(user => (  // ошибка
          <List.Item >
            <List.Content floated='right'>
              <Link to={`/users/updateUser/${user._id}`}>
                <Button>Update</Button>
              </Link>
              <Button onClick={() => dispatch(removeUser(user._id))}>Delete</Button>
            </List.Content>
            <Image avatar src='https://react.semantic-ui.com/images/avatar/small/daniel.jpg' />
            <List.Header>Name: {user.name}</List.Header>
            <List.Content>Surname: {user.surname}</List.Content>
            <List.Content>Date of birthday: {user.dateOfBirthday}</List.Content>
            <List.Content>Phone: {user.phone}</List.Content>
            <List.Content>Email: {user.email}</List.Content>
          </List.Item>
        ))}
      </List>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: что в ошибке сказано?

Comment: `users.slice((currentPage * 10), 10)` — условно, на 5-й странице получается `slice(50, 10)`, а должно быть `slice(50, 60)`, соответственно → `.slice((currentPage * 10), currentPage * 10 + 10)`

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME Я исправил, но показывает только 5 элементов и только на первой странице

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const currentPage = 2;
const array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23];

const updatedArray = array.slice(currentPage * 10 , (currentPage * 10) + 10).map(item => item);

console.log('updatedArray', updatedArray);
```